# Cypress.Commands.add is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Chainable

Tags: azure-active-directory, automated-tests, cypress

I tried to follow this example

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/azure-active-directory-authentication
Need it to run my automated Cypress test against Azure Active Directory login authentication

and got into this problem

[image]

I tried this in a fresh project with different versions of cypress also, same result

Answer (score 3):

This page explains [Types for Custom Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-Custom-Commands) how to provide type support for custom commands.

> When adding custom commands to the cy object, you can manually add their types to avoid TypeScript errors.

Create a type definition file `cypress/support/index.d.ts`. In that add something like

```js
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to log in to AAD.
       * @example cy.loginToAAD(username, password)
       */
      loginToAAD(username: string, password: string): Chainable<void>
    }
  }
}
```

Also in `tsconfig.json` make sure your type definition file is in the `types` path.